# Conversion text file into csv using perl

Tags: perl, csv

I have long text file and I want to convert it in spreadsheet. It consists of Id, Name, Length and sequence. Every new protein starts with (>) sign and order are Id, name Length and sequence on new line

Example

```
1 > LPT_ECOLI, 190-255 (Clockwise), Thr operon leader peptide 
KRISTTITTTITITTGNGAG
2 > AK1H_ECOLI, 337-2799 (Clockwise), Bifunctional aspartokinase/homoserine dehydrogenase I
MRVLKFGGTSVANAERFLRVADILESNARQGQVATVLSAP
```

Output

Table will be

```
Id Length Name Sequence
LPT_ECOLI 90-255(Clockwisw) Thr operon lader peptide KRISTTITTT
```

Comment: So what is the problem? What have you tried so far and how did that fail?

Comment: I don't know how to ignore '>' of every line and 1 more problem is that every protein contains sequence on new line so how to write code for it ?

Comment: Your output isn't a CSV. There should be some delimiter separating fields, like a comma.

Comment: I want to save it in spreadsheet. Like Id will be save in Id column only.

Comment: With all of these folks writing free code, why hasn't anybody used https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::WriteExcel yet?

Answer (score 2):

With a somewhat awkward `sed` script:

```
sed -nE '/^[0-9]+[ \t]+>/ { s/^[0-9]+[ \t]+>[ \t]+//; h; n; x; G; s/\n/,/; s/[ \t]*,[ \t]*/,/g; p }'
```

Output:

```
LPT_ECOLI,190-255 (Clockwise),Thr operon leader peptide,KRISTTITTTITITTGNGAG
AK1H_ECOLI,337-2799 (Clockwise),Bifunctional aspartokinase/homoserine dehydrogenase I,MRVLKFGGTSVANAERFLRVADILESNARQGQVATVLSAP
```

This you can import in your spreadsheet as CSV.

**Edit:** Same thing with Perl if you insist:

```
perl -lpe 'chomp($_ .= "," . <>) if (s/^\d+\s*>\s*//o); s/\s*,\s*/,/g'
```

Comment: As with fugu's solution, I can't be certain why the down vote, but a Perl solution was requested. (And if you take issue with this, I agree, I don't know what that should matter; that part isn't justified.)  Also the solution while compact is to me a little cryptic.  I think it would be helpful to have a description in English as to what that sed is doing so that if some of the assumptions that it requires are not met it may give an idea of what/where to change.

Comment: I understand csv files. look I want to convert that text file in spreadsheet. Because its very huge file. First i want to delete all this '>' signs. then 1st column will be ID consists of name protein (LPT_ECOLI next row AK1H_ECOLI etc) 2nd column will be Length (190-255 (Clockwise) next row 337-2799 (clockwise)) 3rd column name ( Thr operon leader peptide next row  (Bifunctional) 4th column sequence etc. Like that. As my text file is very big, so I am trying to use array.

Comment: I don't see the connection between "text file is very big"  necessitating "tyring to use array"?  None of the solutions given use arrays, although one uses a hash table as noted.

Answer (score 2):

Provided your `IDS` are unique this will do what you want:

```
my ($id, $length, $name, $sequence);
my %data;
while(<DATA>){
    chomp;
    my @split = split(/,/); 
    ($id, $length, $name) = @split[0..2] if /^\d+/;
    $id =~ s/^\d+\s>\s//;
    $data{$id} = [$name, $length, $_] if /^[A-Z]/;  
}


open my $out, '>', 'out.csv' or die $!;
print $out "Id,Length,Name,Sequence\n";

foreach my $id (sort keys %data){
    ($length, $name, $sequence) = @{$data{$id}};
    print $out "$id,$length,$name,$sequence\n";

}

__DATA__
1 > LPT_ECOLI, 190-255 (Clockwise), Thr operon leader peptide 
KRISTTITTTITITTGNGAG
2 > AK1H_ECOLI, 337-2799 (Clockwise), Bifunctional aspartokinase/homoserine dehydrogenase I
MRVLKFGGTSVANAERFLRVADILESNARQGQVATVLSAP
```

This works by splitting your data on `,` and building a hash of arrays, using the ids as keys and the other information as values. This can then be printed to a `.csv` file.

Comment: Dunno why the down vote, but the requirement that ID's are unique wasn't explicitly indicated and doesn't feel needed. If the data is huge, then keeping that hash around is going to slow things down. That said, it's also true that the problem domain and requirements is also not clear.  So this might be perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another option:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while ( my $lines = <DATA> . <DATA> ) {
    print join (',', ( split />\s+|,\s+|\n/, $lines )[ 1 .. 4 ]), "\n";
}

__DATA__
1 > LPT_ECOLI, 190-255 (Clockwise), Thr operon leader peptide
KRISTTITTTITITTGNGAG
2 > AK1H_ECOLI, 337-2799 (Clockwise), Bifunctional aspartokinase/homoserine dehydrogenase I
MRVLKFGGTSVANAERFLRVADILESNARQGQVATVLSAP
```

Output:

```
LPT_ECOLI,190-255 (Clockwise),Thr operon leader peptide,KRISTTITTTITITTGNGAG
AK1H_ECOLI,337-2799 (Clockwise),Bifunctional aspartokinase/homoserine dehydrogenase I,MRVLKFGGTSVANAERFLRVADILESNARQGQVATVLSAP
```

The `while` loop starts by reading in two lines at a time.  The `split` uses a regex to split those lines on " >" or ", " or "\n", and then `join`s  elements 1-4 from the `split` with a comma and `print`s the results.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @fugu - Yes, by concatenating the two reads from the DATA file handle.

Answer (score 0):

And in Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;
open(my $fh, "<", "foo.data") || die;
my $last_was_rec_start = 0;
my ($id, $len, $name);
foreach (my $lineno=1; my $line = <$fh>; $lineno++ ) {
    chomp($line);
    if ($last_was_rec_start) {
        # Add validation that line matches protein sequence?
        print "${id},${len},${name}',$line\n";
        $last_was_rec_start = 0;
        next;
    }
    my @fields = split(/,\s+/, $line);
    unless (scalar(@fields) == 3) {
        print STDERR "Malformed line ${lineno}; expecting 3 comma-delimited fields:\n${line}\n";
        next;
    };
    $len = $fields[1];
    $name = $fields[2];
    unless ($fields[0] =~ /\d+ > (.*)/) {
        print STDERR "Malformed line ${lineno}; expecting number >\n${line}\n";
        next;
    }
    $last_was_rec_start = 1;
    $id = $1;
}
```

Which gives this output on your example:

```
LPT_ECOLI,190-255 (Clockwise),Thr operon leader peptide',KRISTTITTTITITTGNGAG
AK1H_ECOLI,337-2799 (Clockwise),Bifunctional aspartokinase/homoserine dehydrogenase I',MRVLKFGGTSVANAERFLRVADILESNARQGQVATVLSAP
```

Basically the code starts off by reading lines splitting on comma or ",". The first field sub-matched to find remove the number >. After we find a line match
the line after is taken as a sequence line.

However, you might also want to look at [Bio::Perl](http://www.bioperl.org/wiki/Main_Page). It can probably write CSV files and if your input in some standard format it might be able to read that as well.

Comment: Thanks rocky but its giving output same as input format not in table form or in list. And yes input file have standard format.

Comment: I don't think you understand what a CSV is. http://edoceo.com/utilitas/csv-file-format

Comment: OK, is it possible to create table in txt format only?

Comment: "txt format only" is pretty vague. How are you going to figure out where fields end in this "txt only format"?   As lcd047 wrote, you would import this into a spreadsheet program. Please edit your question to clarify what you mean. If this is in a standard format, is it in one of the formats that BIoPerl understands? Also, are you able or willing to put any effort into coding?

Answer (score 0):

Below please find sample code - in working wersion replace `<DATA>` with `<STDIN>` and use execute it as `script < input-file > output-file`

```
use strict; use warnings;

# print CSV header line
print "N, Id, Length, Name, Sequence\n";

my($line1,$line2);
while( defined($line1=<DATA>) and defined($line2=<DATA>)) {
  # put two input lines slurped above into $_
  local $_ = $line1 . $line2;

  my ($N, $Id, $Length, $Name, $Sequence ) = m{
    ^(\d{1,6}) # $N - record numer (?)
    \x20>\x20
    ([A-Z1-9_]{1,128}?) # $Id
    \x20*,\x20*
    ([- ()0-9A-Za-z]{1,128}?) # Length
    \x20*,\x20*
    ([^,\"\'\n\r]{1,256}?) # $Name
    # the quotes (\"\') are escaped/backslashed to make SO syntax coloring work
    \x20*\r?\n
    ([A-Z]{1,4096}?) # $Sequence
    \r?\n
  }sox or die "wrong line format (line $.):\n $_";
  printf "%d, %s, %s, %s, %s\n", $N, $Id, $Length, $Name, $Sequence;
}
die if defined($line1); # incoplete set of input lines;
__DATA__
1 > LPT_ECOLI, 190-255 (Clockwise), Thr operon leader peptide
KRISTTITTTITITTGNGAG
2 > AK1H_ECOLI, 337-2799 (Clockwise), Bifunctional aspartokinase/homoserine dehydrogenase I
MRVLKFGGTSVANAERFLRVADILESNARQGQVATVLSAP
```